# Docker Connection Issue in Spring Boot Microservice - nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused : configserver

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, spring-cloud

I revised an example of Spring Boot Microservices and I have a problem about running all services on docker.

After creating the image file of each services, I devised a docker-compose.yml to run all services on Docker. I noticed some of services throw ConnectException regarding configserver but I have no idea how to fix it. Here are the code snippets to create Docker image for each service.

```
1 ) service-registry
   - mvn clean install
   - docker build -t microservicedailybuffer/serviceregistry:0.0.1 .

2 ) configserver
   - mvn clean install
   - docker build -t microservicedailybuffer/configserver:0.0.1 .

3 ) apigateway
   - mvn clean install -D skipTests
   - docker build -t microservicedailybuffer/apigateway:0.0.1 .

4 ) auth-service
   - mvn clean install -D skipTests
   - docker build -t microservicedailybuffer/authservice:0.0.1 .

5 ) orderservice
   - mvn clean install -D skipTests
   - docker build -t microservicedailybuffer/orderservice:0.0.1 .

6 ) productservice
   - mvn clean install -D skipTests
   - docker build -t microservicedailybuffer/productservice:0.0.1 .

7 ) paymentservice
   - mvn clean install -D skipTests
   - docker build -t microservicedailybuffer/paymentservice:0.0.1 .
```

Here is my `docker-compose.yml` shown below

```
services:

  serviceregistry:
    image: 'microservicedailybuffer/serviceregistry:0.0.1'
    container_name: serviceregistry
    ports:
      - '8761:8761'
    networks:
      - backend

  configserver:
    image: 'microservicedailybuffer/configserver:0.0.1'
    container_name: configserver
    ports:
      - '9296:9296'
    environment:
      - EUREKA_SERVER_ADDRESS=http://serviceregistry:8761/eureka
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://configserver:9296/actuator/health" ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
    depends_on:
      - serviceregistry
    networks:
      - backend

  apigateway:
    image: 'microservicedailybuffer/apigateway:0.0.1'
    container_name: apigateway
    ports:
      - '9090:9090'
    environment:
      - EUREKA_SERVER_ADDRESS=http://serviceregistry:8761/eureka
      - CONFIG_SERVER_URL=configserver
      - ZIPKIN_URL=http://zipkin:9411
      - REDIS_URL=redis://redis:6379
    depends_on:
      - configserver
      - zipkin
      - redis
      - serviceregistry
    networks:
      - backend


  zipkin:
    image: openzipkin/zipkin
    ports:
      - "9411:9411"
    networks:
      - backend

  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    networks:
      - backend


  authservice:
    image: 'microservicedailybuffer/authservice:0.0.1'
    container_name: authservice
    ports:
      - '7777:7777'
    environment:
      - EUREKA_SERVER_ADDRESS=http://serviceregistry:8761/eureka
      - CONFIG_SERVER_URL=configserver
      - spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://database:3306/userdb?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&serverTimezone=Turkey
      - spring.datasource.username=root
      - spring.datasource.password=ippavlova_1990
    depends_on:
      database:
        condition: service_healthy
      configserver:
        condition: service_started
    networks:
      - backend


  productservice:
    image: 'microservicedailybuffer/productservice:0.0.1'
    container_name: productservice
    ports:
      - '8081:8081'
    environment:
      - EUREKA_SERVER_ADDRESS=http://serviceregistry:8761/eureka
      - CONFIG_SERVER_URL=configserver
      - spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://database:3306/productdb?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&serverTimezone=Turkey
      - spring.datasource.username=root
      - spring.datasource.password=ippavlova_1990
      - ZIPKIN_URL=http://zipkin:9411
    depends_on:
      database:
        condition: service_healthy
      configserver:
        condition: service_started
      zipkin:
        condition: service_healthy
    networks:
      - backend

  orderservice:
    image: 'microservicedailybuffer/orderservice:0.0.1'
    container_name: orderservice
    ports:
      - '8082:8082'
    environment:
      - EUREKA_SERVER_ADDRESS=http://serviceregistry:8761/eureka
      - CONFIG_SERVER_URL=configserver
      - spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://database:3306/orderdb?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&serverTimezone=Turkey
      - spring.datasource.username=root
      - spring.datasource.password=ippavlova_1990
      - ZIPKIN_URL=http://zipkin:9411
    depends_on:
      database:
        condition: service_healthy
      configserver:
        condition: service_started
      zipkin:
        condition: service_healthy
    networks:
      - backend


  paymentservice:
    image: 'microservicedailybuffer/paymentservice:0.0.1'
    container_name: paymentservice
    ports:
      - '8083:8083'
    environment:
      - EUREKA_SERVER_ADDRESS=http://serviceregistry:8761/eureka
      - CONFIG_SERVER_URL=configserver
      - spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://database:3306/paymentdb?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&serverTimezone=Turkey
      - spring.datasource.username=root
      - spring.datasource.password=ippavlova_1990
      - ZIPKIN_URL=http://zipkin:9411
    depends_on:
      database:
        condition: service_healthy
      configserver:
        condition: service_started
      zipkin:
        condition: service_healthy
    networks:
      - backend


  database:
    container_name: mysql-database
    image: 'mysql:latest'
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    restart: always
    environment:
      #MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ippavlova_1990
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ippavlova_1990
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - backend
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin" ,"ping", "-h", "localhost"]
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 10


networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  db-data:
```

When I run the docker-compose file through docker-compose up, I get some problems in api gateway.

**Api Gateway Issue**

```
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://configserver:9296/API-GATEWAY/default": Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

How can I fix all these issue?

Here is the repo : [Link](https://github.com/Rapter1990/springbootmicroservicedailybuffer)

Here is the git based system file :  [Link](https://github.com/Rapter1990/springappconfig)

Comment: Your error messages look like you're misusing `localhost`; in a Docker context this almost always refers to the current container, not another container or the non-Docker host system.  It might help on the one hand to reduce the question to the minimum required to demonstrate the problem – can you show the same issue with just two containers, and a minimal set of Compose options? – and on the other to include the configuration options showing what's trying to make these HTTP GET calls.  Can you [edit] the question to contain a [mcve]?

Comment: The `localhost` URLs from the error messages aren't included there, so it's hard to tell.  This will also be easier to debug for only one service at a time and not four all at once.

Comment: as i saw you defined network for authservice and some of your services but didnt define that network for apigatewayservice, put all of your microservices in the same network and try

Comment: how did you used CONFIG_SERVER_URL=configserver in your code?? it seems you used @value or smth like this,chrck that code

Comment: If you use ports attribute in docker compose file, containers access them by http://localhost:8081 like so. If you want to access them as the service id like configservice:8181, that configservice need to add expose attribute in the docker compose file

Comment: add `expose` attribute for configserver instead of ports attribute. Search the difference between expose and ports in docker compose.

Comment: @ikhvjs "Expose" as a Docker verb means almost nothing.  Adding an `expose:` line to your Compose file will do nothing, and it's always safe to delete an `expose:` block if one is present.

Comment: @DavidMaze I revised some codes in docker-compose.yml I still couldn't fix the issue. I get configserver issue in api gateway. I fixed the other issues.

Comment: @ikhvjs I couldn't still the configserver issue regarding api gateway.

Comment: @DaniyalVaghar I couldn't still the configserver issue regarding api gateway.

Comment: What is your docker compose file version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After revising the api gateway shown below, the issue disappeared.

```
  apigateway:
    image: 'microservicedailybuffer/apigateway:0.0.1'
    container_name: apigateway
    ports:
      - '9090:9090'
    environment:
      - EUREKA_SERVER_ADDRESS=http://serviceregistry:8761/eureka
      - CONFIG_SERVER_URL=configserver
      - ZIPKIN_URL=http://zipkin:9411
      - REDIS_URL=redis://redis:6379
    depends_on:
      configserver:
        condition: service_healthy
      zipkin:
        condition: service_healthy
      redis:
        condition: service_started
    networks:
      - backend
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your `application.yml` and `docker-compose.yml` files.

These lines should be present to override the `EUREKA_SERVER_ADDRESS`

```yaml
eureka:
  instance:
    prefer-ip-address: true
  client:
    fetch-registry: true
    register-with-eureka: true
    service-url:
      defaultZone: ${EUREKA_SERVER_ADDRESS:http://localhost:8761/eureka}
```

and to communicate within the container you need to use a common network.
So it should look like this.

```yaml
  serviceregistry:
    image: 'microservicedailybuffer/serviceregistry:0.0.1'
    container_name: serviceregistry
    ports:
      - '8761:8761'
    networks:
      - backend

  configserver:
    image: 'microservicedailybuffer/configserver:0.0.1'
    container_name: configserver
    ports:
      - '9296:9296'
    environment:
      - EUREKA_SERVER_ADDRESS=http://serviceregistry:8761/eureka
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://configserver:9296/actuator/health" ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
    depends_on:
      - serviceregistry
    networks:
      - backend
```

Comment: you have to add networks in docker-compose

Comment: also have to uncomment the eureka section from config server.
Checked your github code https://github.com/Rapter1990/springbootmicroservicedailybuffer/blob/b22e822894d8e7469d065866811897460dcbf8f9/configserver/src/main/resources/application.yml#L17

Comment: I revised some codes and The only problem which I cannot solve is not to connect api gateway to config server.